# Hover img to show an absolutely positioned div isn't working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display absolutely positioned div `#menu`, default state `top: -9999px; left: -9999px` after a user hover over the image (so it should be like `top: 100px; left: 20px`).

But it's not working for me this way.

Take a look at my JSFiddle, maybe there is some mistake:

Here is my Css :

```
#menu{
height: 350px;
width: 280px;
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
top: -9999px;
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NfyP/)

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Why left: -9999px;top: -9999px;??

Comment: Because it should be hidden. I might use opacity: 0 and on hover opacity: 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that will help you get what you need:

**DIV**

```
<div class="menu">
    hi
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .menu {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #06F;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0;
    }

.menu:hover {
     position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7aPvS/4/)

Comment: Thanks. But I can't make it work with hovering another div. Take a look here -http://jsfiddle.net/7aPvS/5/ .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution. There must be a plus in `img:hover` + `#menu`. And I use `opacity` instead of `-9999px`.

```
#menu{
    height: 350px;
    width: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    opacity: 0;
}

#img{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
#img:hover + #menu{
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

Comment: opacity will still take up the space so display:none; would be better